# firebase_messaging not customizing notification when app is not in foreground

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-push-notification

I need to group notifications from firebase about messages comes from users. Firebase push notification is grouping achieved by using `**flutter_local_notification**` plugin. This is done inside `onMessage()` callback set up during Firebase configuration. But when app is not in foreground this grouping and other customer styling can not be done. I had given `"tag"` field in `notification` section of Firebase push notification. This will show only one notification according to the `tag`.

But i need to add custom styling also when app not in foreground as like when the app is in foreground. How can i achieve this ?

Comment: did you find solution? there are plenty of issues on firebase_messaging plugin.

Comment: @BloodLoss Not yet.